# I can't get latitudes and longtitudes for countries in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to add latitudes and longtitudes for countries in my sheet. I selected Country Name cell and then transform their data types as 'Geography' in the data section.
Then, for example when I type =A2.Latitude , it couldn't get it. How can I add them? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: What do you define as the latitude and longitude of a *country*?

Comment: @BigBen as coordinate :)

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. What is the latitude and longitude of the United States, which spans *many* longitudes and latitudes?

Comment: Now, I understood you. I can explain what I need . I will use that coordinates to create geospatial visualization, a coordinate which refers to simply a country’s location, is enough for me. So, I couldn’t being specific. What do you suggest in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'Geography' Data Types do not include Latitude or Longitude (or any coordinate) values.

Convert your range to a table (select the top left cell and hit Ctrl+T)

Then convert to 'Geography' data type.  Data >> Geography

When you click in a cell in the table, all of the available Geography fields will be presented in a pull-down:

[image]

You can get Latitude and Longitude values into Excel, but you will need to use an external Function, such as the 'A.CRE GEOCODING EXCEL ADD-IN' which can be found here: https://www.adventuresincre.com/geocoding-excel-add-in/

Answer (score 0):

After converting the location data to geography, select the cell with the geographic data then hold down Ctrl+Shift+F5 keys and if Bing has the latitude and longitude data, they will appear from the dropdown list.